# ActiveRecord Include result not containing the data of related table

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Why is it when i display the jason for @portfolio_items I get the data only for Portfolio and not the technologies but when i do @portfolio_items.technologies I only get the records for the technologies
I want a jason object that contains both

```
    @portfolio_items = Portfolio.includes(:technologies).find(27)

    puts  json: @portfolio_items
```

returns

```
    Portfolio id: 27,
    title: "Portfolio title: 0",
    subtitle: "Angular", 
    body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...", 
    main_image: "https://via.placeholder.com/600x400", 
    thumb_image: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x200", 
    created_at:"2018-12-28 23:18:35", 
    updated_at: "2018-12-28 23:18:35"
```

and

```
 puts  json: @portfolio_items.technologies
```

returns

```
   [#<Technology id: 7, name: "Technology 0", portfolio_id: 27, created_at: 
   "2018-12-28 23:18:35", updated_at: "2018-12-28 23:18:35">,

   <Technology id: 8, name: "Technology 1", portfolio_id: 27, created_at
 :"2018-12-28 23:18:35", updated_at: "2018-12-28 23:18:35">,

  <Technology id: 9, name: "Technology 2", portfolio_id: 27, created_at: 
   "2018- 
   12-28 23:18:35", updated_at: "2018-12-28 23:18:35">]
```

So basically why is @portfolio_items not have the value thats in portfolio_items.technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `.technologies` is a method being called on the `@portfolio_items` object which will return technologies related to it, but it does not mix them together which I think it what you are asking about.  To display this as a nested JSON object you would want something like this.

```
puts @portfolio_items.as_json(include:{technologies:{}})
```

This might help if you are curious about it: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json

Comment: Thank you. Side note we have the same last name. Thank you for that link I just